# Difference between Xcode Project and Playground about Swift error handling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling, swift-playground

- Why do I need to provide general `catch` statement for do-try-catch, even though I'm sure my custom error is only thrown in do-try-catch statement?
- And, why is this behavior different between Xcode Project and Playground?

I tried to use a simple Swift's do-try-catch error in my iOS application.

```
enum FooError: Error {
    case foo
}

func fooFunc() throws {
    throw FooError.foo
}
```

When I call this function, I tried to catch only `FooError.foo` error.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do {
        try fooFunc()
    } catch FooError.foo {
        print("foo error is thrown.")
    }
}
```

But this got a compile error `"Errors thrown from here are not handled because the enclosing catch is not exhaustive"`.

The reason this compile error is thrown is my catch statement is not enough, and I can fix this error by adding general `catch` statement.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do {
        try fooFunc()
    } catch FooError.foo {
        print("foo error is thrown.")
    } catch {
        print("something else wrong happened. \(error)")
    }
}
```

I thought `fooFunc` throws only `FooError`, so the catch statement is already exhaustive without general catch, but it seems I need to add it.

Even the weird thing is the general `catch` statement is not needed when I run this code on Playground.

```
do {
    try fooFunc()
} catch FooError.foo {
    print("foo error is thrown.")
}
```

I was wondering why the error handling behavior is different between Xcode Project and Playground.

Answer (score 2):

If you ever read the Swift Language guide thoroughly, the reason why this happens is not hard to find.

Let's look at what the language guide says:

> The catch clauses don’t have to handle every possible error that the code in its do clause can throw. **If none of the catch clauses handle the error, the error propagates to the surrounding scope.** However, the error must be handled by some surrounding scope—either by an enclosing do-catch clause that handles the error or by being inside a throwing function.

See the bold part? No matters what happens, every kind of error must be handled, maybe not in the `catch` clause, but it has to be handled somewhere. If you don't handle it in the `catch` clause, you need to either mark the enclosing method as `throws` or use `try?` or `try!`.

The code that you ran in the playground does not have any enclosing scope. You're writing the code at a global level. And the way the global scope handles errors is to just crash. Try to run this code in the playground. It does not compile:

```
func a() {
    do {
        try fooFunc()
    } catch FooError.foo {
        print("foo error is thrown.")
    }
}
```

Basically, the global scope handles everything for you. Even just this compiles:

```
try fooFunc()
```